# Navigation Drawer в нескольких активити

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

Здравствуйте. Есть код, он дает возможность открывать левую шторку и добавляет гамбургер. Нужно сделать что бы шторка была на нескольких активити. Вынес логику в данный класс, необходимые активити унаследовал от этого класса. Появился гамбургер но на нажатия не реагирует. В чем ошибка?

```
 public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private String[] mCatTitles;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mCatTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cats_array_ru);
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // подключим адаптер для списка
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mCatTitles);
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new Menu.DrawerItemClickListener());

        // Включаем значок у ActionBar для управления выдвижной панелью щелчком
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


// ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                null,  /* значок-гамбургер для замены стрелки 'Up' */
                R.string.app_name,  /* добавьте строку "open drawer" - описание для  accessibility */
                R.string.app_name  /* добавьте "close drawer" - описание для accessibility */
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }


    //  Слушатель для элементов списка в выдвижной панели
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        if (position == 2) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.email:
                // create intent to perform web search for this cat
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
                intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getSupportActionBar().getTitle());
                // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

}
```

Comment: Какую разметку вы устанавливаете в активностях?

Comment: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout